# Include version in filename in WiX project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, wix, version

I'm using Visual Studio to author my WiX installer. I have it all working, but I need to have the version be a part of the .msi filename. I read that it's a bad idea to rename the msi file. It needs to take the form something like this:

my-product-2-10-23.msi

I have managed to make it work, but it seems really complex.

My question: Is there an easier, or more standard, way of accomplishing this?

Here's what I did:

in my .wixproj file, I created the following:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <InstallerMajorVersion>2</InstallerMajorVersion>
    <InstallerMinorVersion>10</InstallerMinorVersion>
    <InstallerBuildVersion>23</InstallerBuildVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Also in .wixproj, I set the following:

```
<OutputName>local-services-$(InstallerMajorVersion)-$(InstallerMinorVersion)-$(InstallerBuildVersion)</OutputName>
```

The problem is that my WiX code can't access those properties. So, I can't set the version in Definitions.wxi. So, in the .wixproj, I did the following:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>Debug;MajorVersion=$(InstallerMajorVersion);MinorVersion=$(InstallerMinorVersion);BuildVersion=$(InstallerBuildVersion)</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I can access each constant in the .wxs files, so in Definitions.wxi, I have:

```
<?define Version='$(var.MajorVersion).$(var.MinorVersion).$(var.BuildVersion)'?>
```

This works, but it's really convoluted. And when I need to change the version, I have to manually modify the .csproj. This will not be intuitive for anyone else who has to update the project.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to append version at the end of .msi by changing  and  in .wixproj file. Check the below section from the .wixproj file

`<PropertyGroup <ProductVersion>_MAJORVERSION_._MINORVERSION_._MICROVERSION_._BUILDNUMBER_</ProductVersion> <ProjectGuid>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ProjectGuid> <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion> <OutputName>ABCSetup_$(ProductVersion)</OutputName> <OutputType>Package</OutputType> </PropertyGroup>`